# How to manage versions on monorepo with application requires to support multiple releases?

Tags: versioning, release

I try to figure out how to manage versions in an monorepo where one of the packages is an application that needs to support multiple releases.

Assume we have a monorepo with just two packages: `lib` and `app`:

```
repo:
- lib@2.0
- app@1.0 (depends on lib@2.0)
```

`app@1.0` is released `release-app-1.0` tag is created.

We continue to make changes to the code and the repo becomes:

```
repo:
- lib@2.1
- app@2.0-beta (depends on lib@2.1)
```

Now a customer discovers a bug in `app@1.0` caused by code in `lib@2.0`.

Where should I fix this bug?

Ideally, since `lib` currently is in `2.1`, I should fix the bug in `master` and release `lib@2.1.1`, and update `app@1.0` to use `lib@2.1.1`.

But in practice, it poses a few challenges:

1. We need to first checkout `release-app-1.0` first to figure out `app@1.0` is using a SemVer compatible `lib` in order to determine we can implement the fix in `master`.
2. After we make the changes in `master` and release `lib@2.1.1`, should we (and how) back port all those changes to the `release-app-1.0`? It would be close to impossible to cherry pick all changes only related to `lib` from `master` to `release-app-1.0`. But if we don't do that, then when we release `app@1.0.1` and create tag `release-app-1.0.1`, the monorepo link between `app` and `lib` is broken (`app@1.0.1` depends on `lib@2.1.1`, but in that tag `lib` is still in `2.0`)

On the other hand, if we fix `lib@2.0` directly and release `lib@2.0.1`, we do not get any benefit of using SemVer and get all the new features/bug fixes in `lib@2.1`.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the components in the monorepo have independent versions and can be updated independently, that could be an indicator that using a monorepo is not appropriate in that scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that one way to do monorepo is to use the same version across all packages, but doing independent version is also a common approach. e.g. `lerna` supports such mode: https://github.com/lerna/lerna#independent-mode

and monorepos such as `react` uses this approach: https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/9a5f28dbedc2b2edd01d216e347ab24b8efa73fc (notice that some packages do not update to the same version).

Comment: The main difference is that these packages (e.g. `react`) do not need to support multiple versions. So the problem I'm describing does not apply.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my own take on this, after collecting ideas from other people.

First of all, let's state the benefits of monorepo:

- reduce the need of publish chaining:

  - `package-a`: change and publish
  - `package-b`: update `package-a`, change and publish
  - `package-c`: update `package-b`, change and publish
  - ...and so on
- symbolic link or direct reference to source code (for scripting language such as JavaScript):

  - changes are immediately available for test runner to use

For this question, we are not going to talk about ultra large repo such as Google.
We will focus on small to large monorepo, for example:

- https://github.com/facebook/react/ or
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript

The only difference is that we need to support previous releases for a substantial period of time (1-3 years).

Let's use the same example:

```
repo:
- lib@2.0
- app@1.0 (depends on lib@2.0)
```

Before releasing `app@1.0`, there is essentially just one branch: `master`.
The version tags for `lib@1.0`, `lib@2.0` and `app@1.0` are all under `master`.

as we continue to develop, the repo becomes:

```
repo:
- lib@2.1
- app@2.0-beta (depends on lib@2.1)
```

where version tags for `lib@2.1` and `app@2.0-beta` continues the trend and every thing are linear under `master`, something like this:

```
lib@1.0 ... lib@2.0 ... app@1.0 ... lib@2.1 ... app@2.0-beta (master, HEAD)
```

Now the customer issue occurs.
We check out the `app@1.0` tag, and discover the issue is inside `lib@2.0-dev`.
It is `lib@2.0-dev` because there might be some changes for `lib` since the `lib@2.0` tag (e.g. chore changes, does not trigger a version bump).

So at this point, we can do two things:

1. fix the problem in `lib` and publish it as `lib@2.0.1`
2. checkout `master`, fix the bug there, and publish it as `lib@2.1.1`

The benefits of (1) is that it is simple, and the changes are minimal, so if you do not have a strong test suite, you can do this approach. But the disadvantage is that if there are other bug fixes in the latest `lib`, you will not get them (e.g. the new `lib` is actually `lib@2.1.15`).

If we choose (2), we will need to update the `lib` dependency in `app@1.0` to `lib@2.1.1` (whether explicitly by specifying `"lib": "^2.1.1"`, or rely on lock file to get the latest version).

The problem then becomes should we somehow update the `lib` package in the `app@1.0.1` branch so that we can still benefit from using monorepo.

There is where the opinion really split:

a) If you don't update, then your process is treating all older releases and separate silos and disregard all benefits monorepo brings for them.

This is a reasonable approach if your releases are short lived, and/or you value workflow simplicity over development convenience.

b) If you update, then you will follow the following process:

1. cherry pick (or rather, straight copy) the latest `lib` code to the `app@1.0` branch, and do a commit.
2. implement the fix needed in `lib`, commit (and optionally bump version, but don't tag), but do not publish.
3. cherry pick the changes you made on `lib` to `master`, tag the `lib@2.1.1` version, and publish
4. publish `app@1.0.1`

Step 3 and 4 can be swapped to make the workflow more straight forward.
It is listed this way for logic reasoning.

Note that the version tag for `lib@2.1.1` is made on `master` instead of under the `app@1.0` branch, so that the version tracking and history is easier to maintain.

Comment: Very informative answer - especially the "straight copy then commit" part - that was the hardest part for me. It's important to specify in the commit message something like  "Manual merge of lib@2.1.1". It's still unclear to me how you would track that lib@2.0.1 is up-to-date with lib@2.1.1 other than looking at the commit messages.

Answer (score 4):

Theres no solution to this problem where you automatically get the fixes you apply to earlier versions in later versions.

You have to fix v2 and release v2.0.1 and seperately fix v2.1 releasing 2.1.1

For all you know v2.1 has been completely refactored internally. The code change you did to fix 2.1 might not even compile in 2.1

The Cherry Pick is a Lie!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand that, but the question is for `app@1.0`, optimally it should get `lib@2.1.1` as it is compatible to `lib@2.0.0`. So the question is how to manage that in a monorepo.

One solution someone pointed out is to release `lib@2.1.1` in `master`, copy all changes in the `lib` project to the `release-app-1.0` tag/branch, to keep the monorepo links working there.

Comment: hmm, surely the compatiblity of you app with its libraries is unrelated to which version you choose to compile it with? A customer might not want to upgrade to the next minor version for a number of reasons, although of course you can choose to stop supporting older versions

Comment: By compatible I mean Semantic Versioning, `lib@2.1.1` is compatible to the version range of `lib@^2.0.0`, so it is "safe" to compile `app@1.0` (to be `app@1.0.1`) with `lib@2.x.x` which will have the targeted bug fix as well as other bug fixes and non-breaking features.

Answer (score 1):

A bug should be fixed in the earliest release that is affected, in this case `release-app-1.0`, bumping `lib` to `2.0.1`. This fix can then be merged or cherry-picked into `master`, bumping `lib` to `2.1.1`.

Comment: Yes that is true, but the problem is about how the app dependency handled and if there is a way to keep the benefits of monorepo in the release branches.